# CSS : round_div is not responsive to its parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have [image: this image].

when I resize my window then it looks like [image: this]

It is not responsive.

```css
.discussion_round_div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: thin #edf1f2 solid;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  left: 36%;
  top: 20px;
}

.discussion_round_div_icon{
  position: relative;
  top: 18%;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  color:#adadad;
}

.discussion_icon_text{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #3d4354;
}

.padding_30{
  padding:30px !important;
  
  }

.bg-dark{
  background:#000;
  }


.discussion_small_round_div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: #2d3446;
  bottom: 9px;
  left: 15px;
  float:right;
}

.discussion_small_round_div:after {
  content: '\2807';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color:white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel discussion_panel_div no_background no_box_shadow" style="position: relative;">
                    <div class="panel-heading padding_30 no_border_radius bg-dark set_padding_0">
                      <div class="discussion_small_round_div pull-right cursor_pointer" id="pending"></div>
                        
                    </div>

                   
                    <div class="discussion_round_div">
                        <div class="text-center discussion_round_div_icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check "></span>
                            <p class="discussion_icon_text">Approved</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**PS:** The round div should be in the center of panel div as per the image

Can I do it without using media query?

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have width defined it is fairly easy:

```
.discussion_round_div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: thin #edf1f2 solid;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  left: 50%; /*changed*/
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: -35px; /* added */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.discussion_round_div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: thin #edf1f2 solid;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  position:relative;
  margin:auto ;
  margin-top:-62px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /*left: 36%;*/
  top: 20px;
}

.discussion_round_div_icon{
  position: relative;
  top: 18%;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  color:#adadad;
}

.discussion_icon_text{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #3d4354;
}

.padding_30{
  padding:30px !important;
  
  }

.bg-dark{
  background:#000;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel discussion_panel_div no_background no_box_shadow" style="position: relative;">
                    <div class="panel-heading padding_30 no_border_radius bg-dark set_padding_0">
                        
                    </div>

                   
                    <div class="discussion_round_div">
                        <div class="text-center discussion_round_div_icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check "></span>
                            <p class="discussion_icon_text">Approved</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Sure, it works, but you haven't explained why. How is this useful to someone who comes across this answer in the future?

Answer (score 0):

could you try to put :

```
.discussion_round_div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: thin #edf1f2 solid;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  left: 50%;
margin-left: -35px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

and tell us.
PD: this revision of cs is not tested

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this.

```
.discussion_round_div {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: thin #edf1f2 solid;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This will keep round div always center. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to center an absolute positioned element is by using:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

This is a better version of [the classic trick](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/) that uses a negative margin since **you don't need to know the width of your centered element** for this solution to work.

So, just add:

```
.discussion_round_div {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: thin #edf1f2 solid;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/w3aL94cL/). I think is perfectly centered...

Comment: still it has a space to the left side.

Comment: extremely sorry... can't it be from the center of right side small circle div?

Comment: I don't get you... what do you mean @Rishi? The "approved" circle is horizontally centered. Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: @JordiNebot see the update snippet of Rishi.Above word of `approved`  icon was moving to left. see the fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/98d2sb7w/ .and drag the output screen.With low size. But your fiddle is already fixed that

Answer (score 0):

If you want the white approved element to be in the center even if you resize the browser then you can use something like:

```
.class{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -100px;   // if your white approved element width is 200px then set margin to -100
}
```

Good luck

Comment: `px`, `em` for example